# What is the type of discontinuity at $x=0$ in $f(x)$ = {$\sin(1/x); x<0$ and $1/x ; x>0$}?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Left hand limit is oscillatory limit and Right hand limit is infinite limit then is it infinite discontinuity or oscillatory discontinuity?

Comment: Do you mean $\sin \frac1x$? In any case, not every discontinuity belongs to a category.

Comment: This might interest you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities

Comment: Since $f$ is not defined at $x=0$ there is no discontinuity there.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $f(0^-)=0$ and $f(0^+)=\infty$, so the limit does not exist at $x=0$, hence there is essential (non-removable) discontinuity at $x=0$.